# Vectorized code to find the position and length of runs of 1s in a bit matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to write something like an adjusted run-length encoding for row-wise bit matrices. Specifically I want to "collapse" runs of 1s into the number of 1s in that run while maintaining the same number of 0s as original (right-padding as necessary). For example:

```
input_v = np.array([
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
])


expected_v = np.array([
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0]
])
```

My current attempt works after padding, but is slow:

```py
def count_neighboring_ones(l):
    o = 0
    for i in l:
        if i == 0:
            return o
        o += 1

def f(l):
    out = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(l):
         c = count_neighboring_ones(l[i:])
         out.append(c)
         i += (c or 1)
    return out
```

Are there some vectorization techniques I can use to operate on the entire matrix to reduce row-wise operations and post-padding?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are the dimensions of typical data you hope to compress in this way? Can you not just use Numpy's built-in sparse matrix support?

Comment: I'm doing this because I need to pass the result to library code I don't control. It's normally small dims but it happens many times.

Comment: What is the library you're passing to?

Comment: I don't think it matters.

Comment: I think it does, if you want a review. But hey, it's your life

Comment: I'm specifically asking about how to vectorize _this_ code, not code outside the scope. It's an MVCE.

Comment: MVCEs are for StackOverflow, not Code Review. Code Review explicitly requires full context.